# Return clob in Oracle case statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

i have a query that returns 3 rows, i am nesting the columns of each row next to each other:

Row 1 - ABC
Row 2 - DEF
Row 3 - GHI

and i'm returning
Row - ABCDEFGHI

The problem is one of the columns is an image that i return as base64 encoded clob.

In order to format this columns in this way ABCDEFGHI i am using a similar sintax to this:

```
max(decode(rownum, 1, columnA)) as A,  
...  
max(decode(rownum, 2, columnD)) as D,  
...   
max(decode(rownum, 3, columnG)) as G,  
...
```

Supposing G is the clob column and is not possible use decode i'm trying to use case

```
max(case rownum when 1 then base64encode(image_file) end),
```

But im getting the following error

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

Is it possible to return a clob inside of case statement ?

Comment: Do you really want to calculate the maximum of your base64 strings plus a literal 1 or it's some kind of typo?

Comment: So big do these images get? Bigger than 4000 chars long?

Comment: 1- No basically im doing when rownumber is 1 Then column ABC, when rownumber 2 then column DEF, when rownumber 3 then column GHI these works fine for the other columns except the CLOB.    

2-No, they dont. actually if i do select base64encode(image_file) from .... this returns the data encoded properly /9j/4RiDRXhpZgAATU0AKgA...

Comment: @APC i already worked around but yes i reallized my images went bigger than 4000 chars i limited the size of my images because i didnt required big images.